# How can I display author name in a Woocommerce shortcode

Tags: php, woocommerce, shortcode, author

I have implemented the WooCommerce shop on a custom page with [their shortcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/).

The WooCommerce shortcodes have many attributes, but does not seem to not include something equivalent to: `[show author="true"]`

How can I work around this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode ('[products limit="10" columns="3"]'); ?>
```

Even outside the shortcode implementation of WooCommerce, there seems to be few, if any alternatives to output the author name.

Would really appreciate help with this problem!

Comment: Yes, you can display author info. where do you want to display it? be specific.

Comment: Apologies if I have not been clear enough. I would like to display the author info below the title of each product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` action hook check below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_author_info_after_title', 2 );
function show_author_info_after_title() { 
    global $product; // global product object
    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // product id 
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $product_id);
    $product_author = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id );
    echo '<p class="product-author">' . $product_author . '</p>';
}
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I added the code to my functions.php file and reloaded the shop page, but the author name is still not showing. I checked the inspector and it does print "<p>class="product-author"</p>, but with no name. Could there be a problem with the code or perhaps I have overlooked something really obvious?

Comment: I will back to you.

Comment: I don't know why this is not an accept answer, well it works for me.